# How can I substring to specific character in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, substring, jupyter

For example, I have 2 columns(1,2), and in table 2 I want to fetch everything until " character.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
df.columns = ['1','2']

a = df['2'].str[:' " ']

print(a)
```

but is not possible since I need a number

```
    column 2 example

1234@gmail.com, 12@gmail.com", blah blah
1234@gmail.com", ....
123@gmail.com", ...
1234@gmail.com, 1234@gmail.com, 1234@gmail.com", blah
```

return everything until " character.

Comment: `df['2'].str.extract('(.*)"')`.

Answer (score 2):

Split the string on `"` and pick the `first` element.

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['2'].str.split('"').str[0]
```